# Wrong glyphs displayed when using emWin and Korean fonts

Tags: c, unicode, utf-8, fonts, embedded

I am using `SEGGER emWin` on an embedded system.

I have downloaded a Korean font: [Korean True Type Font](http://www.fonts2u.com/category.html?id=95)
And converted the font to C language data statements.

When I printed the text:  한국어 ("Korean"), nothing printed out.
The hex code for the text (UTF-8) is: `\xED\x95\x9C\xEA\xB5\xAD\xEC\x96\xB4`

I opened up the font in the Font Creator and noticed the glyph at offset `0xED` does not match the first glyph in the text.  Also, there are no glyphs at offset `0xED95` or `0x95ED`.

I converted the file using 16-bit Unicode.

The hex code for the text was determined by using Google Translate, then copying the text into Notepad, saving the text as UTF-8 and then opening up the text file with a hex editor.

How do I get the hex string to print the appropriate glyphs?

Am I having a Unicode vs. UTF-8 issues?

**Edit 1:**
I am not calling any functions to change the encoding, as I am confused on that part.
Here's the essential code:

```
// alphabetize languages for display
static const Languages_t Language_map[] =
{
    {"Deutsch", ESG_LANG_German__Deutsch_},
    {"English", ESG_LANG_English},
    {"Espa\303\361ol", ESG_LANG_Spanish__Espanol_},
    {"Fran\303\247ais", ESG_LANG_French__Francais_}, /* parasoft-suppress MISRA2004-7_1 "octal sequence needed for text accents on foreign language text" */
    {"Italiano", ESG_LANG_Italian__Italiano_},
    {"Nederlands", ESG_LANG_Dutch__Nederlands_},
    {"Portugu\303\252s", ESG_LANG_Portuguese__Portugues_}, /* parasoft-suppress MISRA2004-7_1 "octal sequence needed for text accents on foreign language text" */
    {"Svenska", ESG_LANG_Swedish__Svenska_},
    {"\xED\x95\x9C\xEA\xB5\xAD\xEC\x96\xB4",ESG_LANG_Korean}, // UTF-8
//  {"\xFF\xFE\x5c\xD5\x6D\xAD\xB4\xC5", ESG_LANG_Korean}, // Unicode
};

   for (index = ESG_LANG_English; index < ESG_LANG_MAX_LANG; index++)
    {
        if (index == ESG_LANG_Korean)
        {
            GUI_SetFont(&Font_KTimesSSK22_12pt);
        }
        else
        {
        GUI_SetFont(&GUI_FontMyriadPro_Semibold_22pt);
        }
        if (index == language)
        {
            GUI_SetColor(ESG_WHITE);
        }
        else
        {
            GUI_SetColor(ESG_AMR_BLUE);
        }
        (void) GUI_SetTextAlign(GUI_TA_HCENTER);
        GUI_DispStringAt(Language_map[index].name,
            (signed int)Language_position[index].x, 
            (signed int)Language_position[index].y);
    }
//...

    void GUI_DispStringAt(const char GUI_UNI_PTR *s, int x, int y) {
      GUI_LOCK();
      GUI_pContext->DispPosX = x;
      GUI_pContext->DispPosY = y;
      GUI_DispString(s);
      GUI_UNLOCK();
    }
```

The GUI_UNI_PTR is not for Unicode, but for "Universal":

```
/* Define "universal pointer". Normally, this is not needed (define will expand to nothing)
   However, on some systems (AVR - IAR compiler) it can be necessary ( -> __generic),
   since a default pointer can access RAM only, not the built-in Flash
*/
#ifndef GUI_UNI_PTR
  #define GUI_UNI_PTR
  #define GUI_UNI_PTR_USED 0
#else
  #define GUI_UNI_PTR_USED 1
#endif
```

Comment: UTF-8 is variable-length. In this case the three-byte sequence 0xED,0x95,0x9C represents the character U+D55C Hangul Syllable han `한`. Suggest post some code to show how you're trying to print. Are you calling `GUI_UC_SetEncodeUTF8`?

Comment: @bobince: I have added the code.  Is there a function to switch back from UTF8?

Comment: `GUI_UC_SetEncodeNone` looks like an inverse function, but I'd expect you'd normally want to stay in UTF-8. Certainly `Português` and `Français` are in UTF-8. (`Espa\303\361ol` is not valid UTF-8, however, so no idea what that is.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The emWin is performing correctly.
The system is set up for UTF-8 encodings.

The issue is finding a truetype unicode font that contains all the glyphs (bitmaps) for the Korean language.  Many fonts claim to support Korean, but their glyphs are in the wrong place for unicode.